# Why database stores characters as ??? while they are rendered correctly in API response?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, character-encoding, special-characters, collation

I have a RESTFul POST endpoint that saves Data into MYSQL database. One of the table columns is expected to store special characters such as  ❤️ . When they are saved, I see that in database not all characters are stored correctly. For example the above characters are stored as ? ❤️ ?.

But when the same record is retrieved with a GET endpoint the characters are successfully retrieved and they have retained their values.

the column collation details are :CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci

My JDBC URL has this param : `&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8`

Is there a way that  one can see correct values stored instead of `???`

Answer (score 0):

The 'woman' and 'kiss' are non-BMP characters hence need `utf8mb4`, not `utf8`, in MySQL.  This, together with `? ❤️ ?`, indicates that `utf8` is mentioned somewhere.  Check

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%'.

SHOW CREATE TABLE ...
```